# How to identify baseURI?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

Suppose i uploaded a folder of images in pinata and got a CID and a URI for that. Then I uploaded the metadata folder which contains metadata for each images. I got a CID and URI for that metadata folder too, from pinata. My question is among these 2 URIs which URI is baseURI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `baseUri` would be the CID of the metadata folder. Your metadata folder contains the metadata of each image or NFT. And every metadata further contains the CID of the image.

Thus, use the metadata folder's CID as your `baseURI`.